# Heroku: custom domains not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I'm trying to add custom domains to two Heroku apps and it's not working. I've done it before without a problem.

On the Heroku website, I added Zerigo DNS (in the add ons section) and then added the domain name. On Godaddy, I changed the nameservers to

```
a.ns.zerigo.net
b.ns.zerigo.net
c.ns.zerigo.net
d.ns.zerigo.net
e.ns.zerigo.net
```

I did that yesterday (24 hours ago). It's always worked within two hours before.

I know there's also a way to add custom domains through the console. When I try to do this

```
heroku addons:add custom_domains:basic
```

I get a response "App not found" even though I can view the app (which is just a blog) live on the internet.

Update
Trying suggestion in the comments i got

```
heroku addons:add custom_domains:basic --app hollow-cloud-8495.heroku.com/
Adding custom_domains:basic to hollow-cloud-8495.heroku.com/... /Users/michael/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-rc1@ruby193/gems/heroku-api-0.2.4/lib/heroku/api.rb:64:in `rescue in request': undefined method `response' for #<Excon::Errors::StubNotFound:0x000001028649a0> (NoMethodError)
    from /Users/michael/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-rc1@ruby193/gems/heroku-api-0.2.4/lib/heroku/api.rb:59:in `request'
    from /Users/michael/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-rc1@ruby193/gems/heroku-2.26.5/lib/heroku/auth.rb:29:in `request'
    from /Users/michael/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-rc1@ruby193/gems/heroku-api-0.2.4/lib/heroku/api/addons.rb:34:in `post_addon'
    from /Users/michael/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-rc1@ruby193/gems/heroku-2.26.5/lib/heroku/command/addons.rb:76:in `block in add'
    from /Users/michael/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-rc1@ruby193/gems/heroku-2.26.5/lib/heroku/helpers.rb:232:in `action'
    from /Users/michael/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-rc1@ruby193/gems/heroku-2.26.5/lib/heroku/command/addons.rb:75:in `add'
    from /Users/michael/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-rc1@ruby193/gems/heroku-2.26.5/lib/heroku/command.rb:176:in `run'
    from /Users/michael/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-rc1@ruby193/gems/heroku-2.26.5/lib/heroku/cli.rb:9:in `start'
    from /Users/michael/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-rc1@ruby193/gems/heroku-2.26.5/bin/heroku:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/michael/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-rc1@ruby193/bin/heroku:19:in `load'
    from /Users/michael/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-rc1@ruby193/bin/heroku:19:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Do you get the problem when `heroku addons:add custom_domains:basic --app YOURAPPNAME` ? ... and try the same when you `heroku auth:login` and then run the add ons?

Comment: @JesseWolgamott tried your suggestion. see update in op.

Comment: Looks like you should talk to Heroku support about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem not so long ago. This is the response.

Hello,

We are currently experiencing some issues with provisioning new domains through the Heroku-Zerigo interface. Operations are looking into the item. We have had no reports of any issues with current domains, only provisioning new ones.

Please set up only the mydomain.com domain. The www will function as a record within the  mydomain.com domain.

For the time being, please create a Zerigo Free account ( 
https://www.zerigo.com/managed-dns/pricing - click on FreeDNS and 
SignUp .)

We can then transition the domain over to your proper Heroku account 
once the items are fully resolved.

- https://www.zerigo.com/docs/managed-dns/creating_your_first_domain
- https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains

Please contact Heroku support for additional details on the specific records if needed, as certain configurations might require other records.

Best Regards,

Zerigo Support

**Edit**

You need to add the following:

```
yourdomain.com      A record 174.129.212.2
yourdomain.com      A record 75.101.163.44
www.yourdomain.com  A record 75.101.145.87
```

Comment: When you logon to Zerigo's dashboard, you will be able to rub tests on the domain

Comment: thanks. On Zerigo, did you do the step of adding an Address host record i.e. Heroku's ip address as per the instructions. If so where did you find Heroku's IP address?  "First we're going to add an "A", or Address host record. This record provides the information necessary to turn a domain (example.org) into an IP address (172.16.100.99). In this case we're assuming this is a webserver, so you should use the IP address of your webserver here."

Answer (score 1):

After encountering the same error (and reading this post) I signed up for a zergio account and discovered Vezu's way is not the best way. After adding your domain, just click "add snippet" and select "heroku" from the drop down menu and it will configure you everything for you.

In fact the configuration it does for you is nothing like the IP's Vezu suggests, and falls more in line with the [guidelines laid out by Heroku.](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/what-ip-addresses-should-i-use-to-point-my-custom-domain-to-heroku)

Comment: interesting, but it's good to know the way described by Vezu because it helped me configure the domain to use gmail i.e. add gmail's mx records